# Merging two Observables with one taking higher priority

Tags: c#, system.reactive

Is it possible to use ReactiveExtensions to achieve the following;

- Two Observables, one which is "High" priority and the other "Low"
- Merging both Observables into one, which can then be subscribed to, with intention that this resulting Observable will always emit high priority items ahead of any low priority ones.

I understand that this could be more trivially implemented using two `ConcurrentQueue` collections and something like this;

```
return this.highPriorityItems.TryDequeue(out item) 
    || this.lowPriorityItems.TryDequeue(out item);
```

But this approach has problems like not being "subscribable" in the same manner that an Observable would be (so once the queues are depleted, processing would end without a lot of extra guff to push this off into a Task).

Furthermore, I'd be interested in applying some extra filtering on the queues, like throttling and "distinct until changed", so Rx seems like a natural fit here.

Comment: So the "low" observable hands (whatever this new piece of code is) a value. What's this code meant to do? Wait forever to see if the "high" observable will *ever* produce another value? I'm struggling to see how the priorities could ever work and just keep coming back to using `Merge` and ignoring priorities.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever, the idea is basically "Merge" but with high priority items skipping to the front. Does that make sense? I do want to process both sources of items in the same way, hence the Merge and a subscription that wouldn't know about priority. But it's the order in which they arrive that I'm focusing on - imagine I have 20 low priority items coming through, and a new high priority one gets submitted. I want that to be emitted next, not after the 20 other items.

Comment: But you only ever see one item at a time. If the "low" priority has passed you five items so far and *intends* to send you 15 more, what of it? And you certainly have no way of discovering that fact purely from observables anyway.

Comment: Like you said, my subscription wouldn't know or care about priorities or the volume of items "in the pipe", but surely there's value in arranging the order in which the merged observable emits its next item? Say my subscription is to display a notification, and various low priority ones are being streamed in. But suddenly, a very important message needs displayed next, so you would want it to "jump the queue" and be the next thing that the subscription processes. This is the spirit of what I'm hoping to achieve with two merged Observables and one subscription.

Comment: your question is confusing because Rx doesn't really have a concept of items sitting in a queue waiting to be processed.  Please draw a marble diagram of the behavior you expect.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

What you are describing is of course a priority queue.

Rx is all about *streams* of events, rather than queues. Of course, queues *are* used a lot in Rx - but they aren't a first class concept, more part of the implementation detail of Rx's concepts.

A good example of where we need queues is to deal with a slow observer. Events are dispatched sequentially in Rx, and if events arrive faster than an observer can deal with them, then they must be queued against that observer. If there are many observers, then multiple logical queues must be maintained, since observers may progress at varying paces - and Rx chooses not to keep them in lock-step.

"Back-pressure" is the concept of observers providing feedback to observables in order to allow for mechanisms to handle the pressure of a faster observable - such as conflation or throttling. Rx doesn't have a first-class way of introducing back-pressure - the only built in means an observable has of monitoring observers is via the synchronous nature of `OnNext`. Any other mechanism would need to be out of band. Your question relates directly to back-pressure, since it is only relevant under the case of a slow observer.

I mention all this to provide the evidence for my claim that Rx is not a great choice for providing the kind of priority dispatch you are looking for - really, a first-class queuing mechanism seems a better fit.

To solve the problem at hand, you need to manage the priority queuing yourself, in a custom operator. To restate the problem: what you are saying is that if events arrive during the observer handling of an `OnNext` event, such that there is a build-up of events to dispatch, then rather than the typical FIFO queue that Rx uses, you want to dispatch based on some priority.

Something to note is that in the spirit of how Rx doesn't keep multiple observers in lock-step, concurrent observers will potentially see events in a different order, which may or may not be an issue for you. You can use a mechanism like `Publish` to get order consistency - but you probably don't want to do this since the timing of event delivery would get quite unpredictable and inefficient in that scenario.

I'm sure there are better ways to do this, but here is one example of a priority-queue based delivery - you could extend this to work for multiple streams and priorities (or even per-event priorities) using a better queue implementation (such as a b-tree based priority queue) but I've chosen to keep this fairly simple. Even then, note the significant number of concerns the code has to address, around error handling, completion etc. - and I have made choices about when these are signalled that there are certainly plenty of other valid choices for.

All-in-all, this implementation certainly puts *me* off the idea of using Rx for this. It's complex enough that there are probably bugs here anyway. As I said, there may be neater code for this (especially given the minimal effort I've put in to it!), but *conceptually*, I am uncomfortable with the idea regardless of the implementation:

```
public static class ObservableExtensions
{
    public static IObservable<TSource> MergeWithLowPriorityStream<TSource>(
        this IObservable<TSource> source,
        IObservable<TSource> lowPriority,
        IScheduler scheduler = null)
    {    
        scheduler = scheduler ?? Scheduler.Default;
        return Observable.Create<TSource>(o => {    
            // BufferBlock from TPL dataflow is used as it is
            // handily awaitable. package: Microsoft.Tpl.Dataflow        
            var loQueue = new BufferBlock<TSource>();
            var hiQueue = new BufferBlock<TSource>();
            var errorQueue = new BufferBlock<Exception>();
            var done = new TaskCompletionSource<int>();
            int doneCount = 0;
            Action incDone = () => {
                var dc = Interlocked.Increment(ref doneCount);
                if(dc == 2)
                    done.SetResult(0);
            };
            source.Subscribe(
                x => hiQueue.Post(x),
                e => errorQueue.Post(e),
                incDone);
            lowPriority.Subscribe(
                x => loQueue.Post(x),
                e => errorQueue.Post(e),
                incDone);
            return scheduler.ScheduleAsync(async(ctrl, ct) => {
                while(!ct.IsCancellationRequested)
                {
                    TSource nextItem;
                    if(hiQueue.TryReceive(out nextItem)
                      || loQueue.TryReceive(out nextItem))
                        o.OnNext(nextItem);

                    else if(done.Task.IsCompleted)
                    {
                        o.OnCompleted();
                        return;
                    }

                    Exception error;                        
                    if(errorQueue.TryReceive(out error))
                    {
                        o.OnError(error);
                        return;
                    }

                    var hiAvailableAsync = hiQueue.OutputAvailableAsync(ct);    
                    var loAvailableAsync = loQueue.OutputAvailableAsync(ct);                    
                    var errAvailableAsync =
                        errorQueue.OutputAvailableAsync(ct);
                    await Task.WhenAny(
                        hiAvailableAsync,
                        loAvailableAsync,
                        errAvailableAsync,
                        done.Task);
                }
            });
        });
    }
}
```

And example usage:

```
void static Main()
{
    var xs = Observable.Range(0, 3);
    var ys = Observable.Range(10, 3);

    var source = ys.MergeWithLowPriorityStream(xs);

    source.Subscribe(Console.WriteLine, () => Console.WriteLine("Done"));
}
```

This will print out the elements of `ys` first, indicating their higher priority.

Comment: Thank you James, your explanation has opened my eyes a bit more to the actual purpose and abilities of Rx. You're right of course, the Rx solution is trying to fit a square peg in a round hole. I suddenly feel compelled to read IntroToRx from start to finish again! Thanks again for taking the time to offer this answer, it's much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

You need to take time into account for a problem like this. In the comment above you talk about user notifications. It seems to me that what you want is a way to say is something like this: Display the most recent notification, unless there is a high priority notification, in that case display that.

Bubble diagrams will make it easier to reason about this. One character is one second:

```
High  : ---------3---5-6
Low   : 1--2-------4----
Result: 1--2-----3---5-6
```

Is that what you had in mind? Would you like to buffer messages and display them later? Like in this case, is it ok that message 5 would only be visible for 2 seconds?

Comment: (1) this is a comment, not answer, but I accept the fact that it's an important question and it would be *hard* to express&format it as a comment, so LGTM for me, (2) problem of shorter timespan available to the 5 is one thing, but there's also an important other question: what to do with 4? should it show up some time after 6? and how late after 6? :) and here we go again with asking ourselves, do we really need to drive it like that at the eventstream, maybe just push it as-is and let the GUI component sort them according to priority or whatever else just not this way